# How do I find value of z in this complex equations?

Tags: complex-analysis

Given complex numbers
\begin{align}
w = −2 − 3i \\
y = −3 + 3i \\
z^3=\left( \frac{w}{y}\right)^5
\end{align}
how do I calculate $z$?

I have tried everything possible but then I just finish with calculus long 10 pages. Cans someone help me please?

Comment: did you try polar representation?

Comment: Yes, I get lost with it.

Comment: which part, finding the polar representation, or going from there?

Answer (score 0):

First calculate $$\frac{w}{y}=\frac{(2+3i)(3+3i)}{9+9}=\frac{-1}{6}+\frac{5i}{6}$$
I simply multiplied through with the complex conjugate of the denominator and reduced.

I tried writing on polar form but the solutions are forever ugly. Here are the solutions as given by Mathematica:

```
{{z -> (-719 + 475 I)^(1/3)/(6 3^(2/3))}, 
{z -> -(((-719 + 475 I)^(1/3) (-1)^(1/3))/(6 3^(2/3)))}, 
{z -> ((-719 + 475 I)^(1/3) (-1)^(2/3))/(6 3^(2/3))}}
```

This seems weird since I get the feeling that this is from an assignment you were given?